# Google Chrome hanging in CentOS 7

Tags: linux, centos7

I am using **Linux platform** (**CentOS 7**). sometimes i get my system just hang and then i need to do restart my system directly from power so anyone know how to rectify this issue without restart my system.I am fed up with every time  restart my system. so please help me out.

I know here i will get my answer that's why i posted my question here.

Thanks in advance!!!

Comment: you are facing this problem only with chrome or other application also?

Comment: You can goto text mode and kill chrom process, u will be protect your system from directly shutdown

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can goto text mode and kill the process which process are running in your system,

1. Press **CTRL+ALT+F2** and goto textmode.
2. Type your username and password
3. Write command **ps -eaf|grep chrome** (you can see here which process is
   running and take that process number just like task manager in
   windows)
4. Now need to kill that process so Write command **kill -9 [process#]** 
   once process will kill you can comeback again in graphics mode with
   **CTRL+ALT+F1**

I hope this this answer will helpful for you beacuse this process is work fine for me when my any application stuck. **:)**